# Dart: why superclass constructor is called last in initialization list?

Tags: dart

Dart: why superclass constructor is called last in initialization list?

```
class Foo {
  String name;

  Foo.create(Map map) : 
    name = map.get("name"),
    
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  int value;

  Bar.create(Map map) : 
    value = map.get("value"),
    super.create(map);
}
```

In other language such as java, superclass constructor is called first.

Comment: You made it like that. Java simply forbids it.

Comment: Isn't `create`just a regular method?  Not a constructor?

Comment: it is named constructor in dart.

Comment: @Antoniossss No, Dart requires a superclass constructor to be last in the initializer list.